# ERROR : opencv4nodejs linux for missing module

Tags: javascript, node.js, opencv

I'm trying to use opencv4nodejs in my project.

1. In Windows, this works fine

```js
     const cv = require('opencv4nodejs');
```

2. In Linux, I'm receiving the following error,

   > Unable to find ../node_modules/opencv4nodejs/build/Release/opencv4nodejs

I did try to install the module opencv4nodejs manually, received the message as the package is added.
I'm running it the following way

```sh
node node/app.js
```

Answer (score 3):

I got the same problem.

Try this:

1) move to directory ./node_modules/opencv-build

2) build the lib mannualy

```
$ cd ./node_modules/opencv-build
$ node install.js
```

In my case, it helped that I started the build of **opencv** manually.

Comment: That did'nt work either. Adding what i did below, But really thanks a lot for suggestion.

Comment: The Steps following fixed my problem.

[Follow for OpenCv Installation][1]

1. Deleted the opencv4nodejs folder in node_modules
2. Cloned the Opencv source from Github
3. Created a build using cmake
4. Then reinstalled opencv4nodejs in the project folder.
5. [optional] set env variable `export OPENCV4NODEJS_DISABLE_AUTOBUILD=1`


  [1]: https://docs.opencv.org/4.2.0/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html

Comment: Finnaly, for production usage I chose the option of installing this library in Docker.

https://github.com/justadudewhohacks/opencv4nodejs-docker-images/tree/master/opencv-nodejs


I built the base docker image with the node version I need and run the application from there. I can give a description of this process if you are interested

Comment: Hope these links might be helpful
https://www.bitpi.co/2015/02/11/how-to-change-raspberry-pis-swapfile-size-on-rasbian/
https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/10/26/how-to-install-opencv-3-on-raspbian-jessie/
https://docs.opencv.org/4.2.0/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html
https://answers.opencv.org/question/220468/video-from-ip-camera-cant-find-starting-number-cvicvextractpattern/